# Subtract dynamic value from every value in list

Tags: python

Apologies if my explanation below is poor, but I am fairly new to python scripting.

I'm trying to find a way to product a list of number that subtracting a set_value from an item in a list, then take the new_value and subtract it from the next item in the list, and so on.

For example:

```
subtraction_list = []
set_value = 100
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
set_value - list[0] = 99
new_set_value = 99
new_set_value - list[1] = 98
...
subtraction_list = [99, 97, 94, 90, 85, 79, 72, 64, 55, 45]
```

Regardless, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use the variable name `list`, because it's the name of a built-in function, so you can try this with a simple loop:

```
set_value = 100
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
final_list=[]
for i in lst:
    final_list.append(set_value-i)
    set_value=set_value-i
final_list
>>>[99, 97, 94, 90, 85, 79, 72, 64, 55, 45]
```

Comment: Just noting the change from 'list' to 'lst' as a variable name here - list is an in-built function in python, and generally should not be used as a variable name

Comment: Yes i know, that's why I change it @Elenchus

Comment: Oh okay, sorry, I will add the note, thanks anyway:)

Comment: @MrNobody33 Thank you for the help, and pointing out the variable name! This script worked perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer if you found it helpful, thanks :) @teddygraham

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in a functional way by leveraging [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to make an iterator the yields the cumulative sum of your list.

It works like this:

```
from itertools import accumulate

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
m = accumulate([0] + l)  # in 3.8 we can use accumulate(l, initial = 0)

list(m)
# [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
```

You can zip this with your value and use it as part of the subtraction allowing you to avoid explicitly managing the state of the variable:

```
from itertools import accumulate

set_value = 100

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
m = accumulate([0]+l)

subtraction_list = [set_value - diff - n for diff, n in zip(m, l)]
# [99, 97, 94, 90, 85, 79, 72, 64, 55, 45]
```

For something completely different – if you are using python 3.8, you can use the walrus `:=` operator here:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
set_value  = 100
subtraction_list = [set_value := set_value - n for n in l]
```

[One note: don't use `list` as a variable name. [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) is a built-in type in python that you can overwrite, which leads to hard-to-find bugs.]

Comment: Thank you for the help, and the heads up! I changed the value of the variable above to lst.

Answer (score 1):

Simlply loop through the list

```
subtraction_list = []
set_value = 100
list_of = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for i in range(len(list_of)):
    set_value = set_value - list_of[i]
    subtraction_list.append(set_value)
```